# how to split string according to tag name in an HTML page using String.split()

Tags: java, html, string, split

I want to split the following string according to the td tags:

```
<html>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr><td>data1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>data2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>data3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>data4</td></tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

I'v tried `split("h2");` and `split("[h2]");` but this way the split method splits the html code where it finds `"h"` or `"2"` and if Iam not mistaken also `"h2"`.

My ultimate goal is to retrieve everything between `<td>` and `</td>`

Can anyone please please tell me how to do this with **only** using `split()`?

Thanks alot

Comment: Why would you want to use split for this? Is it homework or a puzzle? Or is this actually going to be used in production code? (I hope not!)

Comment: Do you mean `<h2>`, or `<td>`?

Comment: @Mark Byers. It is a homework.

Comment: @Matt Ball. Doesn't matter which tag name. But in the code sample I gave I meant <td> :).

Comment: Perhaps you could use this opportunity to show your teacher how to parse HTML properly. On the one hand he might fail you for not following the instructions, but on the other hand maybe he'll realize that teaching people to parse HTML using split is a bad idea and in future teach his students about using HTML parsers instead. Then you'll be a hero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### No.

That would mean — in essence — parsing HTML with regex. [We don't do that 'round these parts.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/)

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to solve your optimal goal:

```
String html = ""; // your html
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<td>([^<]*)</td>", Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);

for (Matcher m = p.matcher(html);  m.find(); ) {
    String tag = m.group(1);
    System.out.println(tyg);
}
```

Please note that this code is written here without compiler but it gives the idea.

BUT why do you want to parse HTML using regex? I agree with guys: use HTML or XML parser (if your HTML is well-formatted.)

Comment: delete last  m = p.matcher(html) in for  () or you will endlessly match the first match.

Comment: @Roo, thank you. You are right and I have edited my answer according your recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

You [cannot](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html) successfully parse HTML (or in your case, get the data between TD tags) with regular expressions. You should take a look at a simple HTML parser:

```
import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.swing.text.MutableAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTML.Tag;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit.ParserCallback;
import javax.swing.text.html.parser.ParserDelegator;

public static List<String> extractTDs(String html) throws IOException {
    final List<String> tdList = new ArrayList<String>();

    ParserDelegator parserDelegator = new ParserDelegator();
    ParserCallback parserCallback = new ParserCallback() {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        public void handleText(final char[] data, final int pos) {
            buffer.append(data);
        }
        public void handleEndTag(Tag t, final int pos) {  
            if(Tag.TD.equals(t)) {
                tdList.add(buffer.toString());
            }
            buffer = new StringBuffer();
        }
    };

    parserDelegator.parse(new StringReader(html), parserCallback, true);

    return tdList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should *really* use a html parser, such as [neko html](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nekohtml/) or [HtmlParser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/).

**Iff** you have a very small set of **controlled** html you *could* (although I generally recommend against it) use a regex such as

```
(?<=\\<td\\>)\\w+(?=\\</td\\>)
```

Answer (score 0):

String.Split or regexes should not be used to parse markup languages as they have no notion of depth (HTML is a recursive grammar needs a recursive parser). Consider what would happen if your `<td>` looked like:

```
<td>
  <table><tr><td> td inside a td? </td></tr></table>
</td>
```

A regex would greedily match everything between the outer `<td>...</td>` giving you unwanted results.

You should use an HTML parser like Johan mentioned.